# Why did they change the Worker of Secrets' voice actor in the "Infinity Blade" series?

Tags: video-games, behind-the-scenes, actors

[Infinity Blade II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Blade_II) was released on December 1, 2011. The character of *[Worker of Secrets](https://infinityblade.fandom.com/wiki/Worker_of_Secrets)* was originally voiced by Simon Templeman but in the [sequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Blade_III) this character is voiced by a different actor, John Noble

Now, don't get me wrong, I think [John Noble](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Noble) is a great actor. After all, he is easily the best part of the *Fringe* TV show. But why in the world did they replace the perfectly good [Simon Templeman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Templeman)?

Comment: Pure guess, but in 2013 (when the principal voice-acting was taking place for IB3, Templeman was starring in a [weekly TV show](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2182229/?ref_=nm_flmg_t_27_act). He evidently managed to find time to voice-act a couple of big-budget console games, but didn't do any voice-acting for mobile games while he was on the show (or since, as far as I can tell).

Comment: The guy from Gamezone who reviewed the game was very excited about John Noble being involved; *"The story details remain a secret, but the trailer (which you can watch below) is cool as fᶧck. Also, John Noble — from Fringe, which I'm currently obsessed with, and Lord of the Rings — has been brought on to voice The World of Secrets. That's the bad guy."* - https://www.gamezone.com/news/infinity-blade-3-unveiled-at-today-s-apple-event-coming-to-ios-september-18/

Comment: I've twitted at Messrs [Templeman](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/1708547753226223641) and [Noble](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/1708549953096708159). Hopefully they'll enlighten us :-)